# How to remove multiple values in an array in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am selecting multiple ion-items from a list but I want to remove multiple same items from an array.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="ion-item optionalItem">
    <button class="ion-button" ion-item *ngFor="let configop of interiorOption" (click)="itemSelected(configop)">
        <span class="color-name">{{ configop.intName }}</span>
        <span class="color-price">{{ configop.price }}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**TypeScript Code**

```
this.Array.push(configop);

for (let key in this.Array) {
    this.Array2.push(this.Array[key])
}

for(let i = 0; i < this.Array.length; i++) {    
    if(this.Array[i] === this.Array2[i])
    {
        this.Array.pop();
    }

    console.log("Sorted",this.Array);
}
```

Comment: please be more specific about what the issue is, what kind of result you wanna get

Comment: i dont want multiple same values in my array.

if a user presses the button "interior" twice or mutiple times. array should store "interior" once. not multiple times.

i want to pop all multiple values from the array.

@Bo Chen

Comment: Why not just check the array if that item exists, and if it exists throw an error at the user stating, "This Item has already been added, please use a new name.." Or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Using Object instead of Array will be a better choice

before click button:

```
object = {
  intName : false
}
```

after click button:

```
if (!object.intName) {
  object.intName = true;
}
```

output all clicked button:

```
for (let key in object) {
  if(object.key) console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help remove dulpicates in an Array.

```
this.newArr = Array.from(new Set(this.oldArr.map((itemInArray) => itemInArray)));
```